# Insert row into another table via mySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to create a trigger to insert a row from one table into another...updating the date and time in the process.  Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO `second_table` (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12)
  (SELECT `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`, `field7`, `field8`, `field9` FROM `first_table` WHERE `field1` = NEW.`field1`), CURDATE(), NOW(), (SELECT `field12` FROM `second_table` WHERE `field1` = NEW.`field1`);
```

This trigger will run when `first_table` is updated.  I'm not sure if this is the correct way to accomplish the task.  I've generalized the field and table names for simplicity.

EDIT:

The columns are identical between the two tables.  I just want the ability to update the date and time when the trigger occurs.  This works, but obviously just copies the previous date and time:

```
INSERT INTO `second_table` (SELECT * FROM `first_table` WHERE `field1` = NEW.`field1`);
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to specify a column list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...the columns are identical between the two tables, I just want to be able to grab the current date and time when the trigger occurs.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's poor practice. What happens if the destination table changes column order or adds/removes a column?

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I'll make that change once I can figure out how to get the updated data that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `second_table` (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12)
 (SELECT `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`, `field7`, `field8`, `field9`, CURDATE() AS `field10`, NOW() AS `field11`, `field12` FROM `first_table` WHERE `field1` = NEW.`field1`);
```